# how to add multiple categories and subcategories in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento, magento2

i just want to many categories and sub catgories in magento 2 ,in bulk .its really time-consuming by adding a single category.Urgent  help neeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 does not have separate import tool for categories but you can create categories via product import. If you have full category path for products in the import file and such category does not exist in Magento 2, it will be created.

CSV example

```
sku,categories
product_sku1,"Default Category/Main/sub, Default Category/Main2/sub2"
product_sku2,"Default Category/Main/sub3, Default Category/Main2/sub4"
```

After product import it will create two products and categories **Main, Main2, sub, sub2, etc...**